# How to map NerdTree commands?

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-nerdtree

I am used the `vifm`'s `hjkl` key maps to navigate and open files. After installing `NERDTree` , I find it difficult as now the `l` key wont open file but will just move the pointer to the left( unlike in vifm where it opened the current file) .

So , I want to map some keys of NERDTree to give me vifm experience . How to do that?

Comment: Do you mean `hjkl` (notice the case)? Based on [this manual](https://vifm.info/manual.shtml#Basic%20Movement), I think that is what you mean, but I'm not certain.

Comment: @JakeGrossman , Ya , I meant `hjkl`. Dont know why I put it in capital letters in the question! . Ya so basically I want to navigate though the files using vifm or ranger like commands

Comment: @JakeGrossman , No actually my problem is not with vifm. It works fine. My problem is with NERDTree. Say for example I want to open a directory using NERDTree , then I have to press `o` to open it. But I want to map the `o` key to `l` key so that a directory opens when I click on `l`

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the NERDTree manual, there is a section called `NERDTreeMappings`
search for "Default Key: o", doing that will take you that particular mapping's description **and** the variable to remap that binding, the variable is named after the "Map setting:" part of the corresponding binding, which for "o" is:

```
Default key: o
Map setting: NERDTreeMapActivateNode
```

so to remap it you would put this in your .vimrc or init.vim

```
let NERDTreeMapActivateNode = 'i'
```

the value can be any binding that you would normally define in a vim map